# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, null, addeventlistener

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4GwvdhrEQg&t=537s and at 5:13 his prototype works but mine does not. I get the error explained in the title of this post

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at window.onload (rico-beweeg-oog.html:29) window.onload @ rico-beweeg-oog.html:29

I can't find any code problem or solution, i have placed the script everywhere in the code, before and after the div elements but it just won't work.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

<style>
#rico {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1060px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #efefef;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#ricobox {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px rgb(255,0,0) solid;
    transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0);
}
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
var rico = document.getElementById('#ricobox');
var container = document.getElementById('#rico').addEventListener("click", klikPositie, false);

alert();

function klikPositie(e) {
    var xPosition = e.clientX;
    var yPosition = e.clientY;

    var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px," + yPosition + "px, o)";
    rico.style.transform = translate3dValue;
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="rico">
        <div id="ricobox"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use ```document.getElementById('rico')``` and document.getElementById('ricobox') without the pound sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because your ids actually are **ricobox** and **rico** without the pound character .

So

```
var rico = document.getElementById('ricobox');
var container = document.getElementById('rico').addEventListener("click", klikPositie, false);
```

should work.

You need to use the # character if you're using jQuery for example `$("#rico")` would be the same as `document.getElementById('rico')`

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tab6ut0/)

Comment: Thank you, the error of the null object is gone! But still, when I click inside the rico div, the ricobox div will not move like it does in the tutorial. Am i missing something, i am just new to learning javascript

Comment: @W.Romijn you have a typo   `var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px," + yPosition + "px, 0)";` you've written **o** instead of **0**

Comment: I would have never noticed it! thank you so much man, it is solved!

Comment: @W.Romijn if any of the answers solves your problem, please don't forget to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var rico = document.getElementById('ricobox');
var container = document.getElementById('rico').addEventListener("click", klikPositie, false);

alert();

function klikPositie(e) {
    var xPosition = e.clientX;
    var yPosition = e.clientY;

    var translate3dValue = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px," + yPosition + "px, 0px)";
    rico.style.transform = translate3dValue;
}
}
</script>
```

There's error on get element id and your translate3d